# Excel spreadsheet with maths

Tags: excel, excel-formula

hi i am having trouble with working out this problem i have been given on excel, i am new to it so please could somebody help me :)

here is the question

A company has an asset valued at £4000 which it believes will lose 5% of its value each year. Create a spreadsheet to show the value of the asset each year for 12 years and the corresponding amount of depreciation.
Ensure that your spreadsheet allows you to change the initial value of the asset and the
depreciation rate easily.
 Use the IF-function to allow you to specify the number of years to list in the table.

Comment: I dont want to do your homework for you mate. You need to use formulas (like IF) to achieve what you want. Maybe have a go first and then come back if you have a specific question?

Answer (score 1):

If A1 contained the 4000 and A2 contained the percentage of depreciation then a formula for the end of that year could be A1/100*(100-A2). Hopefully that makes sense and you have that part and are just unsure on the IF-statement part. Basically what they are asking is to enclose the formula above in an IF that asks if the years are less than those allowed (which you would specify as the question states)

How to use IF - http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/excel-if-statement/

Comment: if A2 contains the percentage, the formula would be `=A1*(1-A2)` or to be correct `A1*(1-A2)^X` (while `X` says how many periods have been passed) ;)